# How to change language from Django URL?

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I want to change the language when the user introduce in the url the locale, something like this http://example.com/es/, http://example.com/es/article-name, http://example.com/en/.

how can I do that?

Comment: +1 for the relevant usage of ¿ :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636604/django-i18n-default-language-without-path-prefixes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checkout [django-locale-url](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl).

It provides a middleware that does exactly what you are asking for, so you don't need to check for the language in urls.py

Comment: But I heard that localeurl monkey-patches core django functions. That's a big concern to me.

Comment: That middleware is currently un-maintained, there is a built-in option in django with language prefix in url pattern

Answer (score 3):

A number of ways to do this that come to mind. Arguably the most "standards compliant" way would be to use the HTTP `Accept-Language` header, which is available to views as `request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` to determine the language in which the user prefers to receive resources and simply return a translated `HttpResponse` in the appropriate language.

Another common way, more along the lines of what you are describing, is to ask the user to select a language on their first arrival and store the selection in the session. Once the user makes a choice, redirect the browser to the appropriate language subdirectory and use relative links in your views so as not to have to worry about crossing languages. You can adjust your URLconf to pass a language keyword to your view like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^(?P<lang>[a-zA-Z]{2})/ ...
```

There is an [Internationalization/Localization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) page on the Django documentation site about i18n that might help you get started.

Comment: really helped. also I took method from http://westiseast.co.uk/blog/django-translation-tools/ and i could do `{%url changeling 'en'%}` in templates

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays the best way is using the built-in  language prefix in url patterns:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns