# Django default language redirects

Tags: django, redirect, localization

Regarding @Cauê Thenório  answer to this helpful [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636604/django-i18n-default-language-without-path-prefixes) related to i18 default languages, 
is there any way to add a 301 redirect when user goes to default language page?

I.E. if your default application language is English, and you go to:

http://www.whatever.com/en/contact/ , it would be great to create a permanent redirect to http://www.whatever.com/contact/

This is specially helpful to avoid Google detects duplicated content in our website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using internationalization in your URL patterns you can simply set the prefix_default_language to False: see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns).

This ''removes the prefix from the default language (LANGUAGE_CODE)''.

It is set to True by default.

Answer (score 0):

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += url(r'^contact/$', contact,
        name='contact')
urlpatterns += url(r'^en/contact/$', contact_redirect,
        name='contact_redirect')
```

**views.py**

```
def default_language_redirect(request):
    return redirect('contact')

def contact(request):
    #....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in webserver level using rewrite tools.

If thats not an option, I would create new [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) that checks if [`request.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes) starts with `/en/` and return 301 redirect.

Comment: I have finally [django_solid_i18n](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls) library and this middleware solution to solve the problem.  

Thanks for the support!