# Get rid of 'en-us' in Django urls i18n

Tags: django, url, internationalization

Using **Django 1.8.17**

I have a lot of 404 in my google stats. This is because some urls are formatted like this:

> http://www.example.com/en-us/some_content_here

I can't figure how to get rid of these en-us lang, best would be to replace with en in this case.

**Here are my i18n settings:**

```
# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGES = (('de', gettext('German')),
             ('en', gettext('English')),
             ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
             ('it', gettext('Italian')),
             ('fr', gettext('French')),
             ('ru', gettext('Russian')),
             ('ja', gettext('Japanese')),
             ('pt', gettext('Portuguese')),)
```

Is there a way to redirect to corresponding languages with default to en if nothing match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using django 1.8 check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865106/2812350).

If you can upgrade to django current version (or 1.10 at least) you'll get native support, check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns).